# MongoDB - check if all values of array are present in query array

Tags: arrays, mongodb

How would you query the following data

```
{
    "colours":["red", "green", "violet"]
}
```

And only match if ALL the colours in the data are in a whitelist of approved colours..

something like an `$allIn` is what i'm after

pseudo code...

```
db.Model.find({
    "colors":{
      "$allIn":["red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "indigo", "violet"]
}});
```

And so the above example would match, but the following data wouldn't as pink is not in the allowed list

```
{
    "colours":["red", "green", "pink"]
}
```

Iv'e been playing with `$all`, `$in`, `$elemMatch` but can't get it to work....

Comment: Thanks @JohnnyHK - couldn't find that answer, exactly what i need.

Comment: Great! Yeah, it's one of those things that's hard to search for.